# is there a way that you can after making a certain pattern in a list the elements of the lists to be completely eliminated?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Task: Complete the following function that filters negative elements out of a list. The function returns the
filtered list and the original list is unchanged. For example, if a list containing the elements 2, −16,
2, −5, 0, 1, −2, −3 is passed to the function, the function would return the list containing 2, 2, 0, 1.
Note the original ordering of the non-negative values is unchanged in the result.

My doubt: I was not able to completely eliminate the list element when a negative number was been detected. Below is my code which replaces the negative number to zero but doesn't completely eliminate it.

Code:

```
def filter(a):
n = len(a)
for i in range(n):
    if a[i] < 0 :
        a[i] = a[i]*0


return a
def main():
a = [1,3,4,-4,3,-6,234,-535,4343,-43433,333,-333,-333,-333]
print(a)
print(filter(a))
```

main()

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new list and append non-negative numbers.

```py
def filter(a):
    new_list = []
    n = len(a)
    for i in range(n):
        if a[i] >= 0:
            new_list.append(a[i])


    return new_list
```

Comment: hi! thanks could you please suggest me a source for practicing basic python exercises?

Comment: I am also not familiar with "append" function could you please write a code which is classic and doesn't use this function?

Comment: @UncalledAstronomer why not? This a very basic list method, used a lot. You should try to learn about it instead of avoiding it...

Comment: Just curious :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using list comprehension:

```
data = [1,3,4,-4,3,-6,234,-535,4343,-43433,333,-333,-333,-333]
non_negative_data = [x for x in data if x >= 0]

print(non_negative_data) # output: [1, 3, 4, 3, 234, 4343, 333]
```

Comment: we can write statements inside the list?

Comment: This concept is called _list comprehension_ - it provides a concise way to create lists. You can read about it here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension and in many more places. Google it...

Comment: is there a way that we can make this code without using functions?

Comment: @UncalledAstronomer no functions here. It's kind of looping mechanism...